# what statistic test to use for measuring the differences between the same individual

Tags: measurement

I am planning to conduct a study to measure the length of the left and right ear on the same individual. I am stumped on which test should i be using and i would be glad if anyone can set me on the right direction. thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of your study? If you're just looking to measure the difference, a [paired t-test](https://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf) may be of interest.

Comment: Are you saying you have lots of individuals each with two ears or a single individual with two ears?

Comment: I would like to measure the length of both ears to see if there is any significant differences among the patient that attend my college. Sorry that i didnt make my self clear.

Comment: Precise wording really helps. I suggest changing your title question so that it doesn’t sound like “one hand clapping.”

Answer (score 2):

You can do various two-sided tests, such as

1. a paired t-test of lengths
2. a one-sample t-test on the difference
3. a regression version of (2)
4. a sign test of matched pairs

Here is an example with some real ear data from Mateen, B., & Sonabend, R. (2019). All I want for Christmas is…Rigorous validation of predictive models to prevent hasty generalisations. *Significance*, 16(6), 20–24. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2019.01336.x.

We cannot detect a statistically significant difference between right and left ear length as the p-value is always above 0.06:

```
. #delimit;
delimiter now ;
. import delimited using "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RaphaelS1/Turing-Ears/main/results.csv", clear;
(encoding automatically selected: UTF-8)
(7 vars, 100 obs)

. drop if missing(llength,rlength);
(12 observations deleted)

. generate rl_diff = rlength - llength;

. ttest rl_diff == 0;

One-sample t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 rl_diff |      88   -.6931818    .3683388    3.455324   -1.425295    .0389314
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mean = mean(rl_diff)                                          t =  -1.8819
H0: mean = 0                                     Degrees of freedom =       87

    Ha: mean < 0                 Ha: mean != 0                 Ha: mean > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.0316         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0632          Pr(T > t) = 0.9684

. ttest rlength = llength;

Paired t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 rlength |      88    66.14773    .6907623    6.479924    64.77476    67.52069
 llength |      88    66.84091    .7074551    6.636518    65.43477    68.24705
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |      88   -.6931818    .3683388    3.455324   -1.425295    .0389314
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     mean(diff) = mean(rlength - llength)                         t =  -1.8819
 H0: mean(diff) = 0                              Degrees of freedom =       87

 Ha: mean(diff) < 0           Ha: mean(diff) != 0           Ha: mean(diff) > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.0316         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0632          Pr(T > t) = 0.9684

. regress rl_diff;

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        88
-------------+----------------------------------   F(0, 87)        =      0.00
       Model |           0         0           .   Prob > F        =         .
    Residual |  1038.71591        87  11.9392633   R-squared       =    0.0000
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0000
       Total |  1038.71591        87  11.9392633   Root MSE        =    3.4553

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     rl_diff | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |  -.6931818   .3683388    -1.88   0.063    -1.425295    .0389314
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test _cons = 0;

 ( 1)  _cons = 0

       F(  1,    87) =    3.54
            Prob > F =    0.0632

. signtest rlength = llength;

Sign test

        Sign |    Observed    Expected
-------------+------------------------
    Positive |          25          33
    Negative |          41          33
        Zero |          22          22
-------------+------------------------
         All |          88          88

One-sided tests:
  H0: median of rlength - llength = 0 vs.
  Ha: median of rlength - llength > 0
      Pr(#positive >= 25) =
         Binomial(n = 66, x >= 25, p = 0.5) = 0.9822

  H0: median of rlength - llength = 0 vs.
  Ha: median of rlength - llength < 0
      Pr(#negative >= 41) =
         Binomial(n = 66, x >= 41, p = 0.5) = 0.0320

Two-sided test:
  H0: median of rlength - llength = 0 vs.
  Ha: median of rlength - llength != 0
      Pr(#positive >= 41 or #negative >= 41) =
         min(1, 2*Binomial(n = 66, x >= 41, p = 0.5)) = 0.0640
```

Comment: Why not the Wilcoxon signed-rank test ?  In this case, the *p*-value is less than 0.05.  (c. 0.03).

Comment: The signed rank test carries an assumption about the symmetry of differences under the null that the sign test need not, which gives the former more power. I don't know enough about ears to know if this assumption is reasonable, so I did not use that test here. Personally, I don't think .03 and .06 are that different since I don't use 0.05 threshold rigidly.

Comment: For those interested in the symmetry assumption for the signed rank test, the following is a good discussion: [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348057/wilcoxon-signed-rank-symmetry-assumption](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348057/wilcoxon-signed-rank-symmetry-assumption)