# What exactly does the “symmetric distribution” assumption of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test refer to?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have two lists (or sets) of data that I would like to statistically compare. More precisely, I would like to check if the difference between data list one and data list two is statistically significant. The data comes from the same sample, hence a repeated measures or paired test is required.

I plotted the data in histograms (shown below) and saw that the distribution in data list two looked far from normal. A Shapiro-Wilk test confirmed this, that is, the data fails the normality assumption in data list two.
The x-axis denotes Pearson correlation results; the y-axis is the number of observations.

[image]

Therefore, instead of using a paired t-Test, I thought of running the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Now, I read in *Boslaugh, S. Statistics in a Nutshell, 2nd Edition (O’Reilly 2012)* on page 317 that

> The Wilcoxon signed rank test does not assume normality but does
> assume at least a symmetric distribution, so it is not appropriate for
> data that are highly skewed.

Question: What does a *symmetric distribution* here exactly refer to, since the Wilcoxon signked-rank test does not require *normality* of the data? Does it simply mean that the data should not show a distribution that is very skewed, as shown in the right plot of data list two?

Comment: It's important to note that symmetry is assumed under the null. So looking at your data to judge symmetry is dubious because the null is probably false. More on that [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/348159/21054).

Comment: I did not know that a symmetric distribution is only assumed under the null hypothesis, and not under the alternative hypothesis. As I now understand it, I can subtract the list two values from the list ones values. Next, I can plot their difference (a new list of data so to speak) using a boxplot. That boxplot, under the assumption of the null hypothesis, should display a distribution that is approximately symmetrical. Is that correct?

Comment: I think that's correct yes, but the point is that you can't use *your data* to do that, because the null is most likely false.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that. In this case, I assume that it would be valid to apply a Wilcoxon signed-rank test, because the null hypothesis is very likely false anyway.

Comment: If the distribution of $r$ relates to a Pearson correlation coefficient, then you might use [a transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) and analyse the sample as if it is (hypothetically) normal distributed. I can imagine that a scatterplot of the transformed pairs can give some intuition about the relations in the data set (difference from the line list1 = list2, correlation between list1 and list2, variations from a multivariate normal distribution, possibly some clusters, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does a symmetric distribution here exactly refer

A symmetric distribution has a probability density or mass distribution for which a reflection through a line leaves the distribution unchanged.

If $m$ is the median then the distribution of the negative and positive values $X-m$ are the same (after taking the absolute value).

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_probability_distribution

---

Why is the symmetry needed?

The signed rank test considers the deviations $\delta_i = X_i -m$ of the observations $X_i$ relative to some hypothetical median $m$.

The negative deviations $\delta_i <0$ and positive deviations $\delta_i > 0$ are compared with each other and the test assumes that the distributions of these negative and positive deviations are the same. That is, the test assumes that the distribution is symmetric around the point $m$.

For a two sample test, symmetry is not needed. The test considers values $\delta_i = X_i - Y_i$ which is symmetric if the distributions $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are the same. The distributions of $X_i$ and $Y_i$ don't need to be symmetric for this.

Below is an example by showing a simulation of two beta distributed variables. You can see that the two variables $X$ and $Y$ are not symmetric themselves, but the difference $X-Y$ is.

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you a lot. The last point concerning the difference between A and B including the Figure clarifies it. Now I understand it.